# Which code does google use for formatting email (it is not bbcode)

Tags: email, formatting, gmail

Once i tried to send email to myself (webmaster@mydomain_name.com.np) from gmail. I got the email in which, bold was surrounded by "**" sign, im sure that it wasn't bbcode, it was similar to those which stackoverflow uses when we ask question, hope i may get the answer, and im sorry for my bad grammar and extremely sorry if im not able to make you understand.